# Reflection GetValue gives a TargetException (nonstatic method requires a target)

Tags: c#, reflection, singleton, invoke

I have a webservice controller that had public static properties, which are webservices. 
I use reflection to invoke methods on those webservices.

When all webservice properties were static, there was no problem at all. This worked good to invoke a method in the webservicecontroller using reflection:

```
Type wsControllerType = typeof(wsController);
PropertyInfo WebserviceProperty = wsControllerType.GetProperty(wsName, Some bindingflags);
MethodInfo method = WebserviceProperty.PropertyType.GetMethod(methodname);
method.Invoke(WebserviceProperty.GetValue(null, null), parameters);
```

The webservicecontroller is converted to a singleton, so the static webservice properties are removed.

When I try to call a method through reflection now, I get a TargetException on the last part (WebserviceController.GetValue(null, null).

I tried multiple things, but can't get it to work. I think i'm missing something simple.. Who can help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to invoke an instance property via reflection you will need to provide an instance to work on.  The post mentioned that `WebServiceProperty` had been turned into a singleton so just use the singleton value

```
WebserviceProperty.GetValue(wsController.GetTheSingleton(), null)
```

Although I must say that it seems a bit odd to even do reflection here.  You have access to the `wsController` type hence you should have the ability to bind statically to all of its members.  Why not just use normal non-reflection here?

Comment: Thanks, works great.. I just didn't see it. My code sample is totally stripped to get to the core problem.
It is used in a base class to find and invoke methods for some objects which are passed. Hard to explain in 1 or 2 lines really, but it saves me a lot of code in every class to use reflection here.